# How to remove 3 or more consecutive letters in java into 2 consecutive letters?

Tags: java, regex, replace, repeat, letters

I'm trying to process strings with repeated chars in order to find the correct word in a dictionary.

The approach I must use is to find words with 3 or more consecutive letters and remove them into 2 consecutive letters.

Then I'll look for in the dictionary if this word exists. If the word doesn't exist, then I must remove the two consecutive letters into 1 letter only.

Example:

```
gooooooood -> good (this existis)
awesooooome -> awesoome (this doesn't exist) -> awesome (this exists)
aaawwwesooooooommmme -> aawwesoomme (this doesn't exist) -> awesome (this exists)
```

I'm working with JAVA and i'm already using this regular expression to get the words with 3 or more repeated letters in a string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w*(\\w)\\1{2}\\w*");
```

Comment: "gggoood" -> "ggood" -> "god"?

Comment: Sasha Salauyou, that's well pointed. In that case, I think I sould always perform first the consonants and then the vowels.

"gggoood" -> "ggoood" -> "goood" -> "good"

Comment: Is that equivalent to remove from 3 the one and from 2 the one?

Comment: @user1201779 "puuupppy" -> "puuuppy" -> "puuupy" -> "puupy" -> "pupy"?

Comment: @user1201779 as you can see, variants of "n repeats"->"2 repeats"->"1 repeat" should be checked in all possible combinations to achieve reliable output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex ("pure version"):

```
(\b\w*?)(\w)\2{2,}(\w*)
```

String version:

```
"(\\b\\w*?)(\\w)\\2{2,}(\\w*)"
```

You should use `replaceAll(regex, "$1$2$2$3")`

## Explanation

```
(\b\w*?) // capture group 1 is lazy
(\w)     // capture group 2 captures the first occurrence of the char
\2{2,}   // char may occur 2 or more times...
(\w*)    // capture group 3
```

Note that the `$number` in the replacement refers to the contents of the corresponding capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1{2,}");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("gooooooood").replaceAll("$1$1"));
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("awesooooome").replaceAll("$1$1"));
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("aaawwwesooooooommmme").replaceAll("$1$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
good
awesoome
aawwesoomme
```

And for the second step, here is how you can do it:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1");
System.out.println(pattern2.matcher("awesoome").replaceAll("$1"));
System.out.println(pattern2.matcher("aawwesoomme").replaceAll("$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
awesome
awesome
```